# FCGI and upload_tmp_dir PHP directive are not working correctly

Tags: php, cgi, fastcgi, mod-fcgid

I run *PHP* as *FCGI*! I'm setting `upload_tmp_dir`  option as value `/home/domain.com/tmp`. When executed `phpinfo()` for double-check it's confirmed that the settings above are correct.

Nevertheless, when actual upload in happening, the uploading file is temporarily going to `/tmp` directory with permissions `apache:apache` and when the upload is fully finished *only* then the uploaded file is being moved to the destination directory, which was set in `upload_tmp_dir`. After file is moved it has *proper* permissions which are `domainowner:domainowner`.

What's happening with `FCGI` as described above is absolutely wrong and different from what `mod_php` or  `CGI` are doing! `mod_php` and  `CGI` just start uploading a file *directly* to the `upload_tmp_dir` and then just *rename* the file after upload is finished.

I have few considerable concerns about this as follows:

Imagine, what happens if 20 people, finish uploading a file that is around 2GB, right at the same time? Uploaded files will have to be moved to the home directory from `/tmp`, creating a lot of useless load on file system! Thus, I thought that moving is much more resourceful rather than just renaming a file in the same directory?! Besides `/tmp` is mounted as `ext3` and home as `ext4` and what is even worse that `/tmp` partition is 16GB of space, which is total disaster from what I have imagined above?

**Question:**

How to force `FCGI` to use `upload_tmp_dir`directive the same way as `CGI` or `mod_php`? I haven't found a documented way to change the temp directory it uses.

Please help!?

Answer (score 0):

This issue was discussed at [bugs.php.net](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=46378). The possible solution is that you need to set read attributes on any parent directory to where your `tmp` folder is, to make it work. It could be a security risk.

I would recommend creating a `tmp` in `/home/tmp` setting *chmod 777* to both `home` and `tmp`

Answer (score -1):

[This thread](http://www.howtoforge.com/forums/archive/index.php/t-48893.html) suggests that it may be due to a security level setting.  If 'medium' then FCGI defaults to the system default.

Not sure what setting it is referencing though since it is referring to a desktop installation.  I will do some digging.

Comment: Well, my friend, thanks but no! I have checked those settings and played with them all ways possible! And like I said, `CGI` and `mod_php` are working correctly! So it's not `suexec` nor `basedir` settings.

Comment: Nevertheless, the tread may be useful to someone. It describes (as you have) a situation where mod_php behaves as expected and fcgi defaults to the system temp dir. It also documents two possible solutions, one involving security/suexec and the other (which fixed the posters problem) as user permissions.

Comment: Thanks again, but unfortunately it doesn't solve a question at all, as none of those recommendations that are in that link are an issue!